# Inheritance design

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a Screen base class from which all other Screens extend. Within this base class I have a ticker that is either turned on or off depending on a val within the DB. I'm reading this val within the base class to determine wether or not to add the ticker to the current subtyped screen. Is this good design ? Is there a better approach ?

Thanks

Comment: As Sean pointed, mixing DB state with a class called 'Screen' is probably the indication of a design problem; 
Moreover, in your case, is it the base class (Screen) that sets the ticker on child classes ? Or are child classes using a method of the parent class to set the ticker ?

Comment: The base class decides wether or not the ticker is to be dispayed and also adds the ticker to the screen. Yep it is a design problem, just looking for sugestions on best method of fixing it.

Comment: It's not that bad, just use a Strategy interface or a config object that's passed in from the outside

Comment: The key question is: when instanciate a derived screen, do you allready know at this point that this screen will never have a ticker line? Or is that completely dynamic depending on external factors? If you _know_ that there will be no ticker, you should likely extend a ticker less screen (from an oo design perspective) and instanciate that one. OTOH if you can't always know if there is a ticker or might be a ticker later, it is a very good approach to let the base class decide this. That is what base classes are for. The opposite: calling a method in the base class from the derived is bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing concerns. A screen shouldn't know where it gets its data from, especially it shouldn't know about databases.

You should either have an interface like `ConfigSupplier` that you pass in to your screen (the standard implementation being one that uses a database) or turn things around with a manager class that assigns configuration values to the screen from the outside.

Comment: This does not answer the base problem. He still will have the same problem after he has switched to a Supplier based solution: should the base class take over responsibility to modify derived objects?

Comment: @Angel feel free to provide an answer that addresses those concerns